# Post/Redirect/Get - persist when refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect, post, get

I have main page, consisting of some checkboxes. User has to mark some of them, and then submit. From there, I make some requests to DB and then pull some data, then display it to the user.

I want to use PRG pattern, so after submit if you refresh the page, you won't be asked 'are you sure blabla...'.

Inside my ASP.NET MVC Code I have 2 methods:

```
public ActionResult RedirectToPreview(DemandLetterModel model)
```

and
    public ActionResult PreviewLetters(DemandLetterModel model)

RedirectToPreview makes requests to DB and gets data back, and then put them on tempdata like this:

```
TempData["Notices"] = EligibleNotices.GetListOfNotices(notices);
TempData["Letters"] = letters;
```

In the PreviewLetters, I have:

```
ViewBag.Notices = TempData["Notices"];
ViewBag.Letters = TempData["Letters"];
return View("Preview");
```

It works, but when you refresh the page, it no longer works because of tempdata. How should I do this? I would prefer without session, as it adds complexity.

Might I cache this data only for that refresh? Are there are methods to solve this?

Comment: fyi - TempData is backed by Session

Comment: It doesn't look like you're redirecting...

Comment: Not sure why you don't want to work with Session. It is the same as TempData.
Also know that TempData only "survives" 1 redirect. ViewBag survives only one view. not 100% sure but maybe your problem is that TempData is no longer valid after "refresh" (seems like redirect).

I can suggest one of the two:
1. Store in session. (call the DB only if the session is null)

2. Use Cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Post/Redirect/Get Pattern is there to solve the duplicate-POST issue. 
It stops things like payments from being submitted twice.

It is not intended to avoid browser dialogues and it shouldn't be a rule to be followed for all POSTs.

That being said, if you insist on doing this, there is `TempData.Keep();`

`TempData` items are only removed after they are read.
When a key is marked for retention, the key is retained for the next request.

Just call `TempData.Keep()` before redirection.

You can specify which keys to keep by specifying like `TempData.Keep("key")`

**Note**
TempData is session backed, so you're still using Session, it's just hidden

Comment: I would disagree. PRG is a good pattern to follow with any POST. Not sure what exceptions you might be thinking of, but even if there's a case where it would be okay to replay the same POST should the user refresh, it's still bad practice to do so.

Answer (score 2):

The correct procedure to follow would look something like:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(Foo model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       // save to database or whatever
       return RedirectToAction("Bar");
    }

    return View(model);
}

public ActionResult Bar()
{
    // retrieve model from database
    return View(model);
}
```

In other words, there's no need for `TempData` or `Session`. The action you redirect to should retrieve whatever it needs. It should be able to operate independently of whether it was redirected to from your post action or simply requested by itself.

Comment: How do you let the user know if the POST was successfull ?

Comment: "Bar" here would be your "success" page. Alternatively, you can utilize TempData to include some sort of success message that you'd independently render.

Comment: and in the "Bar" page, how do you differ if the GET was requested directly by user or post request ? Because it seems to me, that if you dont want to use `TempData` or `database`, then you need another success page. For example GetFormPage, PostFormPage, GetSuccessPage or am i missing something ?

Comment: Typically, your get and post views are the same. Either way you want to show the form: the user is either filling it out for the first time or has made some sort of error that they need to correct. You'd then have a single success view that would be loaded when the user successfully completes the form. This does mean three actions, though: one for the form get, one to handle the post and either return the view on error or redirect on success, and then finally your "success" action that post action redirects to and which loads the success view.